# Mysql alter table add duplicate name error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I write a wp plugin than before.
I try this plugin update.
Current update use alter table sql query.
But I get WordPress database error:

```
$abouts_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $this->abouts_content_table;
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$abouts_table_name} (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            $this->abouts_contents TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY(id)
            )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

dbDelta($sql);

$alter_sql = "ALTER TABLE wp_about_years_content ADD  year_id INT NOT NULL";
try {
    $alter_sql = "ALTER TABLE wp_about_years_content ADD  year_id INT NOT NULL";
    if (!$wpdb->query($alter_sql)) {
        throw new Exception("tablo zaten var");
    }
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
}
```

my error

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your reasoning for adding columns after the fact. But make sure that you are adding column to the same table that you created earlier by changing your `alter` script to call table name dynamically just like in `create` statement.

Then there is no reason for `$alter_sql` to be set twice.

your code should look something like this. pardon my code if incorrect by php skill extremely rusty.

```
$abouts_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $this->abouts_content_table;
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$abouts_table_name} (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            $this->abouts_contents TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY(id)
            )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

dbDelta($sql);

try {
    $alter_sql = "ALTER TABLE {$abouts_table_name} ADD  year_id INT NOT NULL";
    if (!$wpdb->query($alter_sql)) {
        throw new Exception("tablo zaten var");
    }
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
}
```